# Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found when accessing by web

Tags: php, mysqli, centos

Since tonight, without anyone having touched anything, all web accesses to my scripts on a Centos machine report this error. Executing the scripts with the php command on the shell does not produce any error instead. What might have occurred?
The error in the ssl_error_log is the same as in the title; namely:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in
>   /var/www/html/iPhone/inarrivo/php/sharing/dbinfo.inc.php:8\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/iPhone/inarrivo/php/sharing/getSharingsJoin.php(6):
>   include()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/iPhone/inarrivo/php/sharing/dbinfo.inc.php on line 8

This is the php -i result:

php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.16

System => Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 23:06:41 UTC 2016 x86_64
Build Date => Nov  6 2016 00:28:47
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/bcmath.ini,
/etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/posix.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php.d/tidy.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini

PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

---

Configuration

bcmath

BCMath support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
bcmath.scale => 0 => 0

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.4.16

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.comment => #FF8000 => #FF8000
highlight.default => #0000BB => #0000BB
highlight.html => #000000 => #000000
highlight.keyword => #007700 => #007700
highlight.string => #DD0000 => #DD0000
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

1. List item

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.29.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
Largefile => Yes
NTLM => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
krb4 => No
libz => Yes
CharConv => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version => NSS/3.21 Basic ECC
ZLib Version => 1.2.7
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.3

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
Default timezone => UTC

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.1
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

ereg

Regex Library => Bundled library enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id$
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: 2aa8dd57d9c0c655cd45e6e5872bb95fa5ad76cf $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled

gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.4.11
T1Lib Support => enabled
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.5.13
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

gmp

gmp support => enabled
GMP version => 6.0.0

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.17

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version => 20901
libXML streams => enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support => enabled
Multibyte string engine => libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
libmbfl version => 1.3.2

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support => enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check => On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version => 4.7.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mbstring.detect_order => no value => no value
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.func_overload => 0 => 0
mbstring.http_input => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output => pass => pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|application/xhtml+xml) => ^(text/|application/xhtml+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
mbstring.language => neutral => neutral
mbstring.strict_detection => Off => Off
mbstring.substitute_character => no value => no value

mhash

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => 10.1.21-MariaDB
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE => external
MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 10.1.21-MariaDB
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API header version => 5.5.50-MariaDB
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.32 2012-11-30

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => 10.1.21-MariaDB

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.7.17

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.1
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: c5042cc34acebcc0926625b57dff03deebbe6472 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
Native OpenSSL support => enabled

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

Revision => $Id: 32db6705f5b617967a546be3114e178a4138c1ca $

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b >  => \b >

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: 6c4d8062369898a397e4b128348042f5c01b4427 $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user
Registered serializer handlers => php php_binary wddx

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => /dev/urandom => /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length => 32 => 32
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.hash_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 692516840b2d7d6e7aedb0bedded1f53b764a99f $
Schema support => enabled

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7
SQLite Library => 3.7.17

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled
Revision => $Id: e268047b695fe9a43cdf415c429729252347becd $

tidy

Tidy support => enabled
libTidy Release => 25 March 2009
Extension Version => 2.0 ($Id$)

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
tidy.clean_output => no value => no value
tidy.default_config => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

wddx

WDDX Support => enabled
WDDX Session Serializer => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.28
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.1
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 1.1.28

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: 0c033d4e4613d577409950ed7bf8da4b68286d15 $
Zip version => 1.11.0
Compiled against libzip version => 0.10.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.7
Linked Version => 1.2.7

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name
sysvsem
sysvshm

Environment

Variable => Value
NVM_RC_VERSION =>
NVM_IOJS_ORG_VERSION_LISTING => https://iojs.org/dist/index.tab
XDG_SESSION_ID => 427804
HOSTNAME => localhost.localdomain
TERM => xterm
SHELL => /bin/bash
HISTSIZE => 1000
SSH_CLIENT => 85.37.181.130 23568 22
OLDPWD => /var/log
SSH_TTY => /dev/pts/3
NVM_DIR => /home/fabrizio/.nvm
USER => fabrizio
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
MAIL => /var/spool/mail/fabrizio
PATH => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/fabrizio/.local/bin:/home/fabrizio/bin
NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR => https://nodejs.org/dist
PWD => /var/log/httpd
LANG => en_US.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL => ignoredups
SHLVL => 1
HOME => /home/fabrizio
LOGNAME => fabrizio
SSH_CONNECTION => 85.37.181.130 23568 82.223.15.117 22
LESSOPEN => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR => https://iojs.org/dist
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR => /run/user/1000
_ => /usr/bin/php

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
_SERVER["NVM_RC_VERSION"] =>
_SERVER["NVM_IOJS_ORG_VERSION_LISTING"] => https://iojs.org/dist/index.tab
_SERVER["XDG_SESSION_ID"] => 427804
_SERVER["HOSTNAME"] => localhost.localdomain
_SERVER["TERM"] => xterm
_SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
_SERVER["HISTSIZE"] => 1000
_SERVER["SSH_CLIENT"] => 85.37.181.130 23568 22
_SERVER["OLDPWD"] => /var/log
_SERVER["SSH_TTY"] => /dev/pts/3
_SERVER["NVM_DIR"] => /home/fabrizio/.nvm
_SERVER["USER"] => fabrizio
_SERVER["LS_COLORS"] => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
_SERVER["MAIL"] => /var/spool/mail/fabrizio
_SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/fabrizio/.local/bin:/home/fabrizio/bin
_SERVER["NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR"] => https://nodejs.org/dist
_SERVER["PWD"] => /var/log/httpd
_SERVER["LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["HISTCONTROL"] => ignoredups
_SERVER["SHLVL"] => 1
_SERVER["HOME"] => /home/fabrizio
_SERVER["LOGNAME"] => fabrizio
_SERVER["SSH_CONNECTION"] => 85.37.181.130 23568 82.223.15.117 22
_SERVER["LESSOPEN"] => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
_SERVER["NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR"] => https://iojs.org/dist
_SERVER["XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"] => /run/user/1000
*SERVER["*"] => /usr/bin/php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] =>
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] =>
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] =>
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] =>
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] =>
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1489675816.1007
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1489675816
_SERVER["argv"] => Array
(
)

_SERVER["argc"] => 0

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.

If I try to reinstall httpd and apache I get error:

> file /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf from install of
>   php-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
>   mod_php71w-7.1.2-1.w7.x86_64 file
>   /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf from install of
>   php-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
>   mod_php71w-7.1.2-1.w7.x86_64

Comment: `php -i` via command line and `phpinfo();` via web script. Find "Loaded Configuration File"

Comment: the code ? the full error ? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Comment: As requested I added the specific error and phpinfo result. Hoping that shall help to find the problem. Nope, I di not find any solution, as it happened by itself and so it is very hard to understand what happened. Please remove the close hint.

Comment: A collegue told me the issue was due to the fact the HTTP server reports PHP 7.1.2 while the PHP package reports PHP 5.4.16, yet I have no idea how to check and change that.

Comment: I think is not about mysqli extension, maybe is about "include_path" to some external lib.

Comment: How do I know more, frankly I do not know what to do. If I try to reinstall php I am reported a trabsaction error between the php.conf from install of php-5.4.16...file and package mod_php71w-... perhaps the problem is this latter module, how do I remove or substitute it with a compatible one?

Comment: I removed mod_php71w php71w-cli so not having the transaction error any longer, but class mysqli is still not found.

Comment: I also added extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so in php.ini and now the error has gone from the logsw, yet the page has now turned to unreachable without any error as you may see at https://taxiprofessional.net/iPuja/meditators.php. As you may also see the access to the root page works fine, so that does not seem an apache problem.

Answer (score 0):

The various processes been performed are in the comments: I summarize:

1. I removed mod_php71w php71w-cli
2. I added extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so in php.ini